# How do I prove that $ 10 | 4^{n + 2 }+ 5^{n + 2 }+ 4^{n + 3 }+ 5^{n + 3 }$

Tags: divisibility

I have no idea how to prove this. I don't even have an idea where to start from, could someone drop a few hints?

Comment: You have been around for almost two months. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: The expression is not clear (I assume the exponents are $n+2$ and $n+3$). Additionally, the concrete question should be in the body, the title should just be a description what it is about.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I will try to fix it now.

Comment: Nevertheless, a small hint : Show that the expression is both divisible by $2$ and by $5$.

Comment: You can use induction

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I'm struggling with formatting as of now, I will practise later. So sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: With a little modulo-arithmetic, you can show this without induction.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, I've just simplified it to be both divisible by 2 and by 5. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean

$N=5^{n+3}+5^{n+2}+4^{n+3}+4^{n+2}$

Then we have:

$N=5^{n+2}(5+1)+4^{n+2}(4+1)= 5k$

But N is even therefore it must be a multiple of $2\times 5 =10$.

Comment: Did you mean $N$ where you typed $A$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$
4^{n + 2 }+ 5^{n + 2 }+ 4^{n + 3 }+ 5^{n + 3 }
=
5\cdot 4^{n + 2 }+ 6 \cdot 5^{n + 2 }
=
80 \cdot 4^n + 150 \cdot 5^n
$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\ ({a,b\!+\!1})(\color{#c00}{a\!+\!1,b})\mid a^j(\color{#c00}{a\!+\!1}) + \color{#c00}{b^k}(b\!+\!1)\,$ if $\,j,\color{#c00}{k>0}$.

OP is case $\ a,b = 4,5,\ j,k = n\!+\!2$

Comment: Note the factors are coprime $\,(d\mid (a,b\!+\!1),(a\!+\!1,b)\Rightarrow\,d\mid a,a\!+\!1)$ so their lcm = product.